# Do the finite subcovers of open coverings have to be open?

Tags: real-analysis

A set K is compact $\iff \forall$ open coverings there exists corresponding finite subcovers. Do these finite subcovers have to be open also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is always the case automatically. The formulation is a bit unfortunate.

1. We say that a covering $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ is open, if **each set** $U_i$ is open.
2. We say that a covering $(V_j)_{j \in J}$ is finite, if **the index set** $J$ is finite.

Hence, the two adjectives "open" and "finite" refer to completely different things.

Finally, we say that $(V_j)_{j \in J}$ is a subcover of $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ if  for each $j \in J$, there is some $i_j \in I$ with $V_j = U_{i_j}$, i.e. if

$$
\{V_j \mid j \in J\} \subset \{U_i \mid i \in I\}.
$$

If $(U_i)_i$ is an open cover and $(V_j)_j$ is a subcover of this cover, then the above implies that each set $V_j$ is automatically open (because it is one of the $U_i$). Hence, every subcover of an open cover is automatically open.